# No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it 127.0.0.1:8983

Tags: solr, xconnect

I have solr 7.5 working and am able to hit secured admin panel https://solr75:8983.

My connection string settings in index worker and site root are set to https://solr75:8983, my hosts file has an entry for solr -127.0.0.1 solr75 - but I still get this error:

> An error occurred.
>   System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: An error occurred while sending the request. ---> System.Net.WebException: Unable to connect to the remote server ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it 127.0.0.1:8983

I am able to hit my xconnect instance with no errors, SSL thumbprints match. The SSL certificates when I hit https://solr75:8983 are valid and trusted. I don't see 127.0.0.1:8983 entry anywhere. Why is it looking for 127.0.0.1:8983?

Comment: What version of Sitecore?

Comment: sitecore 9.2 and solr 7.5

Comment: Is your Solr certificate trusted? you can check from chrome browser as it should say connection is secure

Comment: Yes, https://solr75:8983 is secured and the certificate is trusted

Comment: Is the xconnect service running? Do you see any errors in the xconnect and sitecore logs?

Comment: Did you try adding “/solr” to the end of the address? I believe it’s required.

Answer (score 1):

"Actively refused it" means that the host sent a reset instead of an ack when you tried to connect. It is therefore not a problem in your code. Either there is a firewall blocking the connection or the process that is hosting the service is not listening on that port. This may be because it is not running at all or because it is listening on a different port.

Comment: Solr75 is set to the default port; 8983. It looks like the domain name is the issue, not the port, right?

Comment: is there any duplicate entry in your host file

Comment: no. Again, I am able to hit https://solr75:8983 with no issues. I have my connectionstring values all pointed to solr75 so the error message is confusing.

Comment: Yes, is confusing issue. When this issue occur ? try to add any core admin in solr

Comment: Check any default  proxy in your web. Config file.

Comment: No issues there. No interactions on my site are being written to xDB and that is when I get this error.